# How to extract data from word document into sharepoint lists 2010

Tags: sharepoint-designer, sharepoint-enterprise, custom-list, word-automation

I have a challenge to extract data from word documents into a SharePoint list.
Users send emails with attached Word documents containing forms filled out by users to be stored in SharePoint list. Implementing incoming email functionality of SharePoint those email will house in SharePoint list.
Now i need to then extract data from that word form into a custom list

I have seen lots of examples about Excel and Access being used for that matter, but not really word. I don't even know where to start.

Can anyone please show me right direction. I would really appreciate your time and effort.

Thank You

Comment: I have a similar enquiry, when I attempt to extract numbers from document properties (such as +2, +1) nothing is showing up on Sharepoint. The text extraction works. I tried changing the Sharepoint type from Single line of text to Number to no avail. Any help appreciated. Thanks.

Answer (score 4):

Does it have to be a list? If the documents are stored in a library, the form fields can be defined as library columns. Within Word these library columns/fields can be inserted into the form via Quickparts > Document Properties.

The user edits the document and fills in the form. The form fields are document properties and will be visible in SharePoint when the document is stored in the library.

Comment: Thank You for your input. I was trying to use sharepoint list because, i am attaching a workflow in list. When new item is created it will start a document review workflow with 3 tasks assigned to 3 reviewer. I dont know if i can perform that using document library.

Comment: Yes you can use workflows with libraries. In fact, if you are reviewing documents, a library would make much more sense than an attachment to list items.

Answer (score 1):

If you need to access document properties metadata then you can use Quick Parts.

In order to access the document text, you will have to use SharePoint and OpenXML to read the document text. Here is an article.. Here are some articles that will give you way ahead with examples.

[SharePoint and Open XML](http://sharepointblog.acando.com/2012/11/08/sharepoint-and-open-xml/)

[Modifying an Open XML Document in a SharePoint Document Library](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/ericwhite/archive/2010/03/24/modifying-an-open-xml-document-in-a-sharepoint-document-library.aspx)

[Modifying Open XML Documents using the SharePoint Object Model](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/ericwhite/archive/2008/12/12/modifying-open-xml-documents-using-the-sharepoint-object-model.aspx)

Answer (score 0):

you can use openxml to read data from word document, and in added eventhandler to excute the insert operator.

Comment: It would be helpful if you could expand on this answer. Thanks.